eclipse selenium webdriver cannot be imported
maven dependencies can you help me please I cant import webdriver , I have tried writing the query manual and also not working ? am unable to execute any test . I have already tried to remove it and re-install it
enter image description here
I have already tried to remove it and re-install it ,


<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>onemain</groupId>
  <artifactId>one</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.21.0</version>
</dependency>

    
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>




Can you show the pom.xml and a screenshot of Maven Dependencies folder from your project explorer?

I have added to the post my pom.xml content , and added a screenshot of my maven dependencies
